Pass the values from one method to another method in gatling scala
I am working on a performance testing for an E2E scenario and There are 9 chain of requests.
In this 9 chain of request, I have two diff set of baseUrl.
Request1: baseUrl1/someUrlPath
Request2: baseUrl2/someUrlPath
Request3: baseUrl1/someUrlPath
Request4: baseUrl1/someUrlPath
Request5: baseUrl1/someUrlPath
Request6: baseUrl2/someUrlPath
.
.
.
Request9: baseUrl1/someUrlPath
Each request is heavily dependent on the test data of previous request's response ( be it response session , some of the response value etc)
How to implement this E2E user journey in gatling scala?
Problems I am facing:

If I am trying to build it in a single simulation class in gatling scala, two different base Url can not be mapped with one httpProtocol

If I build separate httpProtocol, like below:


setUp(
scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol),
scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocolSim)
)
then I can not transfer the values from a method A used in httpProtocol to another method B httpProtocolSim in the chain (as different session in different protocol)
Please let me know if anyone has any strategy or workaround.

can you try to post your sample code up here ?

If you have a multiply base urls the best way is to provide an absolute path for each requests. 
Instead of:
http("...")
 .get("/questions")

You ought to write a full path, which includes the protocol and, essentially, the base URL:
http("...")
 .get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/")

Perhaps, in your scenario, a single base URL predominates. You could define it using http.baseUrl(...) and utilize a relative path in requests. However, for other base URLs, employ a full path."

Let's say you have a response with this json Body:
{
   "Param1":{
      "ParA": "rand_value"
      }
}

As Gatling's document stated here you can perform a check and then extract a value as you want in response, a sample code written in Scala is below
    exec(
        http("name")
            .post("your target URL")
            .body(StringBody("""{your body here}"""))
            .check(jsonPath("$.Param1.ParA").saveAs("yourVarNameURL"))
      )

As the code block above, a request has been made with a validation check and extract was performed, thus the value is saved in virtual user session as "yourVarName" (holds rand_value). To understand more about virtual user session, see here.
When you successfully extract the value, and you want to pass that into next request, simply put as:
    exec(
        http("nameRequest")
            .post("#{yourVarNameURL}") //you passed the value rand_value in here
            .body(StringBody("""{your body here}"""))
      )

In this step, you called to VU session variable by using Gatling's EL #{yourVarName} note that this is different from language's string interpolation ${}, though they have the same effect. Then voila, you successfully passed the value into next action.
All these action are under one .protocols(httpconf), so when you say about Map, I am not sure what exactly your code block looks like to help further.
Return to your question:
If I am trying to build it in a single simulation class in gatling scala, two different base Url can not be mapped with one httpProtocol.

>>> you can have two different base URL with one httpProtocol, as shown in example above and in gatling's document.


Hope this help.
